# Java protected fields vs public getters

Tags: java

What is better practise and why: accessing base class variables through a protected field or a public getter on the private field.

(The getter will be public regardless)

Comment: [Protected fields in base class are bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182653/are-protected-members-fields-really-that-bad).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If there's going to be a public getter anyway, why would you want to expose the field itself more widely than absolutely necessary? That means it's immediately writable by subclasses (unless it's final to start with).

Personally I like all my fields to be private: it provides a cleaner separation between API and implementation. I regard the relationship between a superclass and a subclass as similar to that of a caller and callee - changes to the underlying implementation shouldn't break subclasses any more than they should break callers. The name of a field is an implementation detail which shouldn't impact other classes.

Admittedly my view is occasionally seen as somewhat extreme...

Comment: In my admittedly limited experience, I haven't found good reasons to use protected fields, and it always seems to cause other problems.  I'd agree that it's better to make them private in very nearly all cases.

Comment: @Jon.Could you provide an working example/illustration for this scenario where both the variables/methods in superclass are used in subclass.?Highly obliged to you if you could reply back

Comment: @Deepak: I'm afraid I don't have time to give a full example for every Java answer I give. Why don't you try it yourself, and if you run into problems, ask a question?

Comment: Would like to rephrase the second para in this answer. Designing an *abstraction* with a  [function](https://github.com/shamhub/python_programming/tree/master/2_Python_Standard_Lib/4_Functional_abstraction) or [class](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/0_Java_basics/Language_features/JavaCollections/DblyLinkList.java) actually drives you to pick a corresponding access specifier. [SICP](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp12/) definition says: *Abstraction creates a barrier between implementation detail and usage*.

Comment: @overexchange: I think I'd rather leave that as your statement in a comment rather than editing the answer with it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Old question indeed, but we started discussing this a bit at our workplace today since JDK 21 has a new `this-escape` warning which sometimes means that you can "fix" this by replacing a `getFoo()` call to the parent class with directly reading the `foo` field. Now, this obviously breaks encapsulation but I wonder how bad a design this would be considered if the base class **and all the child classes** are in the same codebase (in a single repo)? Would be interesting to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @PerLundberg: Sorry, it's been years since I've worked in Java, so I don't have any educated thoughts on this (and would only edit an answer - discussion in comments isn't really appropriate for SO).

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. Yeah, comments is a bit sub-optimal, but at the same time maybe better than editing the answer if the edit might be contrary to the original author's intent. Either way, thanks for replying, appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

You should always program against the public API of a class, that is, use the public methods.

The reason is simple. Someday in the future, you or someone else might want to change the implementation. This should always be possible. If you rely on instance variable, you limit yourself.

Also, when accessing the variable, you can not control if that variable is read-only nor can you add checks when this variable is changed.

If you use setters/getters, you can allways add validation, checking etc later on. You can also only provide a getter to make a variable read only.

Comment: If someone *exposes* a variable, they should treat it as unchangeable as much as they should a public/protected method. If someone exposes a field and then changes it, they clearly don't care about breaking other developers in the first place, and would quite possibly change methods as well :(

Comment: True. That's why I added so many "should"'s to my comment :)
But most of the time it is easier to maintain an existing public method and just add an overloaded/special version which is why i prefer privat variables (except for public static final constants)

Answer (score 11):

Direct field access is not preferred. Use `public` or `protected` setters and getters.

The getter need not be `public` - if you wan  to hide the data from "outsiders", but give the data to subclasses, use `protected`

Answer (score 8):

Some of Sun's recommendations on controlling access to fields are [here.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) Note that making a field protected exposes it to the package as well, not only to subclasses.  Generally, as stated at the link above, fields should be private unless there is a very good reason not to do so.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `protected` implies the *package private* access level

Answer (score 5):

Effective Java 2nd Edition says

> Item 13: Minimize the accessibility of classes and members
>
> The rule of thumb is simple: make each class or member as inaccessible as
>   possible. In other words, use the lowest possible access level consistent with the
>   proper functioning of the software that you are writing.

So if you are not sure why you need a protected class member (ie you don't need the field to be accessible to subclasses or classes in the same package), then declare it private. If you wish to set it from outside the class, then make a public setter.

However, if your member is final, then making it protected might be ok in some cases (ie it doesn't reveal sensitive information).

One potential security issue I would like to mention is that if you have an array declared protected final (even public final), the array reference is final (cannot be modified), but the objects held in the array are not final (an intruder could change the array contents).

---

*If you know c++, you probably know that*

`const int * someMember`

is different from

`int * const someMember`

The latter is like the final array in java.

---

The fix for the aforementioned security hole is to return a deep copy of the array or return it as a read only list.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you should use Sun's recommendations. There is one big exception: if you're programming for Android.

The reason is performance. With every virtual method invocation, there is overhead involved in using the lookup table to route the method to its object. This overhead is not involved when accessing a local variable.

Here are some links that explain this in a little more depth:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters

http://blog.leocad.io/why-you-shouldnt-use-getters-and-setters-on-android/

It's important to know what you're trying to accomplish:

1. The field's value should be accessible to client code, using a public interface.
2. The field is meant to be used by subclasses.

In plain ol' Java, getters and setters accomplish both tasks. But Android is different. If you're doing #1, then you should use public getters and setters. If you're doing #2, then you should use protected fields. If you're doing both, use both.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to present you with some arguments protecting "protected" fields in Java:
"You may favor accessing base class members using protected fields over public accessors in situation where you need to avoid value validation".
However if this is not the case, then private fields with public accessors should be used, to compliment hermetization.

The principle of getters and setters is to provide validation to the values inputted and outputted to the class member. However, in OOP languages, we operate on objects not classes. Base class and specialized class represent a single object, that is why it is perfectly fine to access specific class members over protected field.

Consider the following abstract example with a car:
 - you have a base class *Car* and the derived class *Porshe*.
 - *Car* class may have field like *engine*, which value is not set in Cars constructor (maybe the type of engine is known only after object initialization)
 - You create a *Porshe* class object that contains some logic used to calculate *engine* type using some external data.

In this example, it is expected that *engine* field has a public getter, so car users know what engine the car has. However, there is no public setter as we expect car drivers not to temper with the engine! That is why, it is perfectly fine to make *engine* a protected field, so the *Porshe* class can set its value at some time in future.

Yes, some people will probably say "then use protected setter!".
And I will repeat: in OOP languages we work with objects not classes.
Single responsibility principle - yes, but as object not as class.
If you say: "at some point if we use protected fields over 3 or 5 inheritance levels, it may be troublesome to understand what happens to the field if each class performs some operation with it". And then I answer: That is another antipattern - your object is probably too big at this point and voids Single Responsibility principle.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing protected fields from a subclass is one of the ways that inheritance violates encapsulation. Using the public API is better for this reason.