# Is there any advantage to using protected variables over getters and setters?

Tags: java

Disregarding the fact that making variables `protected` can be convenient, is there anything that actually necessitates the existence of `protected`?

Comment: You can have an `public void init() { basicInit(); }` and `abstract protected void basicInit()` that must be implemented by the subclasses of your class (just to show an example).

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279662/java-protected-fields-vs-public-getters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even if you use getters and setters (which I personally would - I almost always keep fields private) that doesn't mean that `protected` becomes pointless... it just means that you're likely to make the getters and setters themselves `protected` rather than the variable.

If your question is really about whether `protected` accessibility is useful at all, I'd say it is - it often makes sense to have a member which is only accessible to subclasses. More than that, I sometimes use a protected abstract method to which is *called* by the superclass, but isn't accessible outside the hierarchy.

For example, in the template method pattern you may well have a public method which does some setup, calls a protected abstract method, and then perhaps does some final work too. You don't want the abstract method to be public, because you want to make sure your start/end code is executed... and you don't want to force that code to be called by subclasses explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Consider you want to make a class `car` which contains a variable fuel. You don't want this variable be set from outside directly, because fuel usage depends on the car. However, if someone extends `car`, they should be able to modify it.

```
class Car {
    protected float fuelLevel;
    public float getFuel() { 
        return this.fuelLevel;
    }
    public void drive() {
        this.fuelLevel -= 0.5; // fuel usage of an average car
    }
}


class Ferrari extends Car {
    public void drive() { // override drive method
        this.fuelLevel -= 2; // obviously, a Ferrari consumes much more fuel!
    }
}
```

You could also do the same with a `protected void setFuel(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` properties can be marked `abstract` or can be marked `virtual` and overridden. Using a variable instead of a property prevents this and forces derived classes to directly use the base class' implementation.

Comment: So would making the methods final...